# Confirm if user belongs to group, without memberOf overlay

Tags: ldap, member, openldap, active-directory-group

Please help me understand what filter to use to check if logged in user belongs to certain group (in my case group with gid number 10007),
without using memberOf overlay. Is it even possible? If yes, then how?

Currently I have tried it with using filter:

```
(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(gidNumber=10007))
```

Here's a flow how application is currently logging in user through LDAP.

Logging user in:

```
Mar 16 08:54:50 mail slapd[1073]: conn=2424 op=0 BIND dn="cn=AppUser,ou=Service Accounts,dc=domain,dc=com" method=128
Mar 16 08:54:50 mail slapd[1073]: conn=2424 op=0 BIND dn="cn=AppUser,ou=Service Accounts,dc=domain,dc=com" mech=SIMPLE ssf=0
Mar 16 08:54:50 mail slapd[1073]: conn=2424 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
Mar 16 08:54:50 mail slapd[1073]: conn=2424 op=1 SRCH base="dc=domain,dc=com" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(uid=AdminUser)(objectClass=posixAccount))"
Mar 16 08:54:50 mail slapd[1073]: <= bdb_equality_candidates: (uid) not indexed
Mar 16 08:54:50 mail slapd[1073]: conn=2424 op=1 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
Mar 16 08:54:50 mail slapd[1073]: conn=2424 op=2 SRCH base="cn=Admin User,ou=Admins,dc=domain,dc=com" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(uid=AdminUser)(objectClass=posixAccount))"
Mar 16 08:54:50 mail slapd[1073]: conn=2424 op=2 SRCH attr=uid givenName sn mail
Mar 16 08:54:50 mail slapd[1073]: <= bdb_equality_candidates: (uid) not indexed
Mar 16 08:54:50 mail slapd[1073]: conn=2424 op=2 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
```

Check if user belongs to group with gid number:

```
Mar 16 08:54:50 mail slapd[1073]: conn=2424 op=3 SRCH base="cn=Admin User,ou=Admins,dc=domain,dc=com" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(gidNumber=10007))"
Mar 16 08:54:50 mail slapd[1073]: conn=2424 op=3 SRCH attr=givenName
Mar 16 08:54:50 mail slapd[1073]: <= bdb_equality_candidates: (gidNumber) not indexed
Mar 16 08:54:50 mail slapd[1073]: conn=2424 op=3 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=0 text=
Mar 16 08:54:50 mail slapd[1073]: conn=2424 op=4 BIND anonymous mech=implicit ssf=0
Mar 16 08:54:50 mail slapd[1073]: conn=2424 op=4 BIND dn="cn=Admin User,ou=Admins,dc=domain,dc=com" method=128
Mar 16 08:54:50 mail slapd[1073]: conn=2424 op=4 BIND dn="cn=Admin User,ou=Admins,dc=domain,dc=com" mech=SIMPLE ssf=0
Mar 16 08:54:50 mail slapd[1073]: conn=2424 op=4 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
Mar 16 08:54:50 mail slapd[1073]: conn=2424 fd=23 closed (connection lost)
```

My LDAP schema is as following:

```
domain.com
    Service Accounts (Application Bind Users)
        AppUser
    Admins (Admin accounts)
        AdminUser
    Persons (regular accounts)
        Ted
        Kelly
        Ned
    Groups (Groups to define access level to applications)
        GogsAdmins
            AdminUser
        GogsUsers
            Ted
            Kelly
            Ned
```

Comment: Unanswerable without your schema, but in general the group object will have member-valued attributes, and you have to write a filter that specifies that attribute for equality to the member DN.

Comment: Added schema now:)

Comment: No you didn't. That's a DIT. The schema tells us which object classes you are using for which parts of the DIT. For example, the object class of the group tells us which attribute of the group is member-valued.